# Navigationbar not showing in embed navigationcontroller

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, uinavigationbar

i have a simple UIViewController which i've embed in an NavigationController. Normally this would show a navigation bar, bot it does not.

i'm using storyboard

What settings, do i need to make it show the UINavigationBar, from the navigationController?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When your app will be displayed on an iphone, the navigation bar will be visible.
You can go to the view controller that you want to see the navigation bar on it, and select "Top Bar", and then choose the navigation bar you want to be displayed on the storyboard.

[image: Top Bar]

As well, you should have your NavigationController settings like in the attached photo.